# Vanilla JS: register handler on selector (without jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the past I used this to register an event handler on all elements which match `elementSelector`:

```
$(document).on(eventName, elementSelector, handler);
```

Now I want to do this without jQuery.

On [youmightnotneedjquery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#delegate) I found this pure JS solution:

```
document.addEventListener(eventName, function(e) {
    // loop parent nodes from the target to the delegation node
    for (var target = e.target; target && target != this; target = target.parentNode) {
        if (target.matches(elementSelector)) {
            handler.call(target, e);
            break;
        }
    }
}, false);
```

But I think there is a simpler solution.

I am in the lucky possition, that I don't need to support IE11 any more. Is there a simpler alternative to jquery [on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/)?

Comment: as far as I konw, I think your code snippet is the only option for pure js to register event

Answer (score 1):

Here's a basic snippet. I don't think a loop is necessary, you can rewrite the handler from a callback parameter and use [`Element.closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to determine if the event originated from the selector parameter (or one of its parents).

[See also ...](https://github.com/KooiInc/ClientModules) (especially [extensions.js](https://github.com/KooiInc/ClientModules/blob/master/JQueryLike.js))

```js
const demoEventHandler = (evt, target) => {
  console.clear();
  console.log(`handled for ${
    target.dataset.handle ? "button[data-handle]"  : `#${target.id}`}`);
};

handle("click", "#someSelector, #somethingElse, [data-handle]", demoEventHandler);

function handle(evtType, selector, callback = evt => {}) {
  const cb = selector ? evt => {
    if (evt.target.closest(selector)) {
      callback(evt, evt.target.closest(selector));
    }
  } : callback
  document.addEventListener(evtType, cb);
}
```

```html
<p id="somethingElse">
  <button>Hi</button>
</p>
<p id="someSelector">
  <button>Hello</button>
</p>
<p id="byebye">
  <button data-handle="1">Bye!</button>
</p>
```